# Apache HTTPD's remoteip not working

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy, x-forwarded-for

I've configured remoteip and checked that it's actually loaded. The remoteip.conf is loaded as well. I checked the latter by introducing a wrongly formatted IP in the following (correct) config:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1 10.10.0.1 10.10.0.2
```

Now when a end user loads, I can verify I see the `X-Forwarded-For` header with value **10.10.255.100** which is correct. However the `REMOTE_ADDR` variable in PHP is still the loadbalancers' IPs.

According to every tutorial there is on this subject things should simply work at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seem that `RemoteIPTrustedProxy` does not work when the end-user has an IP in an "internal" network (in this case **10.20.255.100**). I'm not sure why the apache devs chose this intertwining of mechanism and policy (which imo this certainly is). To accept internal network IPs use:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1 10.10.0.1 10.10.0.2
```