# Apache's remoteip module does not populate the client_ip

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, ip, x-forwarded-for

In an intranet environment, I have a relatively involved scenario, all on the same server:

```
IIS server acting as a reverse proxy listening on 443
forwards matching requests to localhost:1080/redmine

Apache reverse proxy is listening on 1080
forwards matching requests to localhost:3001 or localhost:3002 (thin servers in front of Redmine)

Thin1 and Thin2 web servers listening on 3001 and 3002 to handle requests
```

The issue is that Apache's `remoteip` module seems to disregard the `X-Forwarded-For` header. The configuration is:

```
# in the httpd.conf file
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so

# elsewhere, in a VirtualHost declaration

    # define the header to use to retrieve the remote ip address
    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
    RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1 10.101.24.161 ::1
    # for debugging only
    LogFormat "%a %h %{c}a *** %{x-forwarded-for}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" redmine
    #LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" redmine
    CustomLog "logs/access-redmine.log" redmine
```

With the above debugging `LogFormat` I expected, according to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html), the `%a` token to contain the original client's IP. However, I get this:

```
::1 ::1 ::1 *** 10.106.33.206, 10.106.33.206:63804 - - [07/Sep/2022:16:08:24 +0200] "GET /redmine/projects HTTP/1.1" 200 10718 "https://redacted.org/redmine/my/account" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

`%a` or `%{c}a` (see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)) are supposed to contain the client IP but actually, both contain the reverse proxy's IP `::1`. The actual client IP is visible in the log line as `10.106.33.206` via the `%{x-forwarded-for}i` token which incidentally proves that the HTTP header is successfully populated by IIS.

I have attempted all kinds of permutations of `RemoteIPTrustedProxy`, `RemoteIPInternalProxy`, etc. but none have led to successfully populating the `%a` token with the original client's IP address.

(An [apparently similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/722177/apache-httpds-remoteip-not-working) did not answer my problem.)